# How can I disable Django's admin in a deployed project, but keep it for local development?

Tags: python, django

I am currently working in a Django project for which I need access to the admin area for local development, but want to disable it in the deployed site (for security reasons, among others).

How can I achieve this programmatically (*ie* using `settings.py`).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First, establish a scheme so that your production server can have different settings than your development servers.  A simple way to do that is with a source-control-ignored local_settings.py file, but there are many fancier ways to do it.

Then, in your settings.py file, put:

```
ADMIN_ENABLED = True
```

and in your production-only settings file, put:

```
ADMIN_ENABLED = False
```

Then in your urls.py:

```
if settings.ADMIN_ENABLED:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
        # ..maybe other stuff you want to be dev-only, etc...
        )
```

Comment: Nice and clean, as I would expect from Django. Thanks.

Comment: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1873/ (there are several other ways of doing it, but I use something like this).

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to follow the example of the default settings.py with TEMPLATE_DEBUG and use "ADMIN_ENABLED = DEBUG" so you don't forget to turn it off.

Comment: `from django.conf import settings`

Answer (score 11):

@madneon 's answer is terrific but requires an update and a small correction, and unfortunately the suggested edit queue is full.

For the first part, as it implies the use of @Ned Batchelder 's answer, the use of `patterns()` is no longer supported in Django 1.9 and above.

A current implemention could look like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = []

if settings.ADMIN_ENABLED is True:
    urlpatterns += [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]

urlpatterns += [
   # ... Other paths
]
```

For the second part regarding appending to `INSTALLED_APPS`, this needs to go in the settings.py file and cannot be placed in the urls files.

As such, it should be written:

```
if ADMIN_ENABLED is True:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('django.contrib.admin')
```

If you include `settings.` before `ADMIN_ENABLED` you'll get an error.

Answer (score 9):

Extending @NedBatchelder
's answer, you might want to use proper `if statement`, like this:

```
if settings.ADMIN_ENABLED is True:
    ...
```

And also remove `'django.contrib.admin'` from `INSTALLED_APPS = [...]`, and use the same condition:

```
if settings.ADMIN_ENABLED is True:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('django.contrib.admin')
```

This way the module wont be loaded, and for eg. `collectstatic` wont copy unnecessary static files used only in admin (fonts, images, css, js).