# Why can't I disable Django's Admin Console?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my Django application, I was using the built-in admin console to help during development. I now want to disable this admin console.

So I simply went to `settings.py` and removed `django.contrib.admin` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

I figured that should be all that's needed. However, when I do that, and re-start the server, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 173, in check_dependencies
    "Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS "
  ImproperlyConfigured: Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to use the admin application.
```

How can I switch off the Django admin console properly?

**EDIT. Below is the full stack trace:**

```
[2016-09-19 15:50:01] ERROR [django.request:256] Internal Server Error: /api/getProfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 108, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 74, in process_request
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 647, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 522, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/syed.saqibali/kkj-working/kingkajou/KingkajouSite/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 291, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 250, in get_urls
    self.check_dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 173, in check_dependencies
    "Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS "
ImproperlyConfigured: Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to use the admin application.
```

Comment: You should show the rest of the error message. Presumably you've got some other references to the admin app: probably in urls.py at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable Django's admin in a deployed project, but keep it for local development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845239/how-can-i-disable-djangos-admin-in-a-deployed-project-but-keep-it-for-local-de)

Comment: Yes Daniel, that was it. Thanks! Genius. There was a reference to the admin app in my `urls.py`. However, as you can see from the full stack trace (added to the original question), it didn't mention that file at all.